# Codeigniter4 SoapClient PHP7.2.5

Tags: webservice, php7, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

Les cuento un poco, estoy migrando una pequeña aplicación de CI3 a CI4, en donde tengo un consumo a un WebService xxxxxx,

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Login_model extends Model {

private $WS_OPTION;
private $WS_URL;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->WS_OPTION = array(
        'soap_version'          => SOAP_1_1,
        'connection_timeout'    => 15,
        'trace'                 => 1,
        'encoding'              => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $this->WS_URL = 'ip?wsdl';
    
}

public function W_VAL_USR($param)
{
    $data   = array();
    
    //No se reconoce SoapClient
    $client = new SoapClient::($this->WS_URL, $this->WS_OPTION);

    $result = $client->WS_ADM_SOL(
                    array(
                        'arg0'  =>  array(
                            'SOLACC'    => 'W_VAL_USR',
                            'SOLINP'    => $param['usuario'].'|'.$param['clave'].'\\',
                            'SOLMAS'    => ''
                        )
                    )
                );

    $result = $result->return;

    if($result->SOLOUT)
    {
        $result     = $result->SOLOUT;
        $result     = json_decode($result);
        $data       = $result;
    }
    
    return $data;

}

}
```

El método descrito anteriormente, esta testeado sobre un ambiente php5.6 CI3, al hacer lo mismo en un ambiente php7 CI4 este me da error al reconocer **new SoapClient()**.

Por otra parte tengo habilitada la extension correspondiente para el uso de SOAP en PHP7
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería encontrar un poco de información relacionada al como consumir un WS con SoapClient.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion al problema es mas bien un tecnisismo, CI4 trabaja con PSR4 (\) es decir la instancia de SoapCliente debería quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
$client = new \SoapClient($this->WS_URL, $this->WS_OPTION);
```